# rails - How to use onsubmit with form_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to convert below code to `form_for` or `form_tag`.

```
<form onsubmit="foo()">
```

What should I do? I don't want to connect another page(action="/URL").

I just want `function foo()` to fire when this form is submitted.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should be easy to do with either `form_tag` or `form_for`. Example:

```
<%= form_for @model, :html => { :onsubmit => "foo()" } %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= form_tag '#', :html => { :onsubmit => "foo()" } %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6):

This would be much easier with `form_tag` than `form_for`. Try this:

```
<%= form_tag '#', onsubmit: "foo();" do %>

<% end %>
```

Also, don't forget that within `foo()`, it should `return false` so that the form doesn't actually submit!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't see how it is much easier with form_tag?

Comment: With `form_for`, you would need a model as one of the parameters. Since you aren't updating any models with your form (only calling a function), it would make more sense to have `form_tag`, since it only requires a url.

Answer (score 3):

You'll be better putting the `foo();` function into the [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) asset pipeline in Rails:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var foo = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
};
$(document).on("submit", "#form", foo(e));
```

You can accompany this with ...

```
<%= form_tag "#", id: "form" do %>
```